# Proving that $T$ is self-adjoint (or that $A,B$ are vertical to each other)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm facing the following problem:

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $A,B$ be subspaces of $X$ such that $X=A\oplus B$ and $T\in B(X)$ such that $T\vert_A=\text{Id}_A$, $T\vert_B=-\text{Id}_B$. Prove that $T=T^{-1}$ and that $T^*=T$.

The first statement is easy; indeed, if $x=a+b$, then $Tx=a-b$, therefore $TTx=a+b=x$, thus $TT=\text{Id}_X$ and we are done.
But I really can't move on with the second statement. I proved that $T^*=T$ if and only if $A\bot B$:

Indeed, if $T^*=T$, then $<Tx,y>=<x,T^*y>=<x,Ty>$ for all $x,y$, which yields $<Tx-x,y+Ty>=0$. If $a,b\in A,B$ respectively, then for $x=b, y=a$ we have that $<a,b>=0$.
The converse is obvious by taking random $x,y$ and writing them in the form $a+b$ where $a\in A, b\in B$. But I can't prove that $A\bot B$. I tried taking the closure of $A$ and writing $X$ as $X=\overline{A}\oplus\overline{A}^{\bot}$ ,and, since $\overline{A}^\bot=A^\bot$, $X=\overline{A}\oplus A^{\bot}$ but I couldn't move on. Any ideas?

Comment: I do not understand your question. In the third paragraph, you  prove indeed that $T=T^*$ implies $A\perp B$.

Comment: @daw I want to prove that $T=T^*$. My only progress was that $T=T^*\iff A\bot B$. The third paragraph is this proof, but I can't prove that $A\bot B$.

Comment: The part between 'Indeed' and $\langle a,b\rangle=0$ IS the proof of $T=T^*$ $\Rightarrow$ $A\perp B$. Please reread your question and comment and revise.

Comment: @daw $A\bot B \implies T=T^*$ is obvious as i say. So, by proving this equivalence, i prove that the problem "prove that $T=T^*$" is the same as "prove that $A\bot B$". Please reread my question and comment and revise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in understanding here might be that "verticality" of $A$ and $B$ are due to the definition of the direct sum of Hilbert spaces.

For arbitrary Hilbert spaces $(A,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_A)$, $(B,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_B)$, one defines the direct sum as ordered pairs of the form
$$
A\oplus B=\lbrace (a,b)\,|\,a\in A,b\in B\rbrace
$$
which turns into a vector space with componentwise addition and scalar multiplication. Then $A\oplus B$ becomes a Hilbert space under the scalar product
$$
\big\langle (a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\big\rangle_{A\oplus B}:=\langle a_1,a_2\rangle_A+\langle b_1,b_2\rangle_B\,.\tag{1}
$$
Now it is customary to write these elements of not as ordered pairs $(a,b)$, but as a sum $a+b$ *(by identifying $A$ with $A\times\lbrace 0\rbrace\subset A\otimes B$ and same with $B$)*. With this identification, every $x\in A\oplus B$ can be uniquely expressed as $x=a+b$ for some $a\in A$, $b\in B$. So in some sense it is by definition that
$$
\langle x,Ty\rangle=\big\langle a_1+b_1,(\operatorname{Id}_Aa_2-\operatorname{Id}_Bb_2)\big\rangle=\langle a_1+b_1,a_2-b_2\rangle\overset{(1)}=\langle a_1,a_2\rangle-\langle b_1,b_2\rangle=\ldots= \langle Tx,y\rangle\,,
$$
because $A\oplus B$ by definition (1) / construction / assumption are "orthogonal".

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are all correct and You have to assume $A\oplus B$ really means the orthogonal sum. If it is not orthogonal by construction as in Frederiks answer and You take the definition $A\oplus B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$ where $A\cap B=\{0\}$ then You get simple counterexamples like the finite-dimensional $X=\mathbb{R}^2=\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\rangle\oplus\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\rangle$ and $T(\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $T(\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix})=-\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $T$ is a bounded operator that fulfills $T_{|A}=Id_A$ for $A=\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\rangle$ and $T_{|B}=-Id_B$ for $B=\langle\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\rangle$ but is not self-adjoint, what You proved and can check by finding its matrix to an orthogonal basis (e.g. to the standard basis, this yields $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\2&-1\end{pmatrix}$)

Comment: That is a nice counterexample to hopefully further clear up OP's misconception!

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully it is not even confusing, $\langle .,.\rangle _2\neq \langle .,. \rangle _{A\oplus B}$ if $A\not\perp B$ with respect to $\langle .,.\rangle _2$.

Comment: @PeterMelech Thank you,the counter-examples were helpful indeed.